# Download the exchange rate EUR to GBP and GBP to EUR for the last week and save in a txt file

Tags: python

Every week I need to generate a file with the EUR to GBP exchange rate and vice versa from the previous week. I used partly a code I found on the Internet but I don't know how to make it download two tables - EUR to GBP and GBP to EUR at one time.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

# Building blocks for the URL
entrypoint = 'https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/' # Using protocol 'https'
resource = 'data'           # The resource for data queries is always'data'
flowRef ='EXR'              # Dataflow describing the data that needs to be returned, exchange rates in this case
key = 'D.GBP.EUR.SP00.A'    # Defining the dimension values, D -daily. the currency being masured, the other currency.SP00- type of exchange rates.A- teh series variation
# Define the parameters
parameters = {
    'startPeriod': '2022-09-25',  # Start date of the time series
    'endPeriod': '2022-10-03'     # End of the time series
}

# Construct the URL:
request_url = entrypoint + resource + '/'+ flowRef + '/' + key





response = requests.get(request_url, params=parameters, headers={'Accept': 'text/csv'})

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))



ts = df.filter(['TIME_PERIOD', 'OBS_VALUE'], axis=1)

ts['TIME_PERIOD'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['TIME_PERIOD'])

ts = ts.set_index('TIME_PERIOD')

table = ts.tail(7)
print(table)
writePath = 'conversion.txt'
with open(writePath, 'a') as f:
    dfAsString = ts.to_string()
    f.write(dfAsString)
```

What's more, the file writes in this form:
OBS_VALUE
TIME_PERIOD
2022-09-26     0.89404
2022-09-27     0.89275
2022-09-28     0.90268
2022-09-29     0.89485
2022-09-30     0.88300
2022-10-03     0.87070

And I would need just the date and the rate without 'TIME_PERIOD' and 'OBS_VALUE'

Could you help me with this? Thanks :)

Comment: Why do you need two requests? The exchange rate can be derived directly from the CSV and the inverse of that value

Answer (score 0):

Q:-"I would need just the date and the rate without `'TIME_PERIOD'` and `'OBS_VALUE'`"

Do you mean to convert `'TIME_PERIOD'` to `'date'`, `'OBS_VALUE'` to `'rate'`?

If yes you just need to add 1 line then this is code for that:

```py
import requests
import pandas as pd
import io

# Building blocks for the URL
entrypoint = 'https://sdw-wsrest.ecb.europa.eu/service/' # Using protocol 'https'
resource = 'data'           # The resource for data queries is always'data'
flowRef ='EXR'              # Dataflow describing the data that needs to be returned, exchange rates in this case
key = 'D.GBP.EUR.SP00.A'    # Defining the dimension values, D -daily. the currency being masured, the other currency.SP00- type of exchange rates.A- teh series variation
# Define the parameters
parameters = {
    'startPeriod': '2022-09-25',  # Start date of the time series
    'endPeriod': '2022-10-03'     # End of the time series
}

# Construct the URL:
request_url = entrypoint + resource + '/'+ flowRef + '/' + key





response = requests.get(request_url, params=parameters, headers={'Accept': 'text/csv'})

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(response.text))



ts = df.filter(['TIME_PERIOD', 'OBS_VALUE'], axis=1)

ts['TIME_PERIOD'] = pd.to_datetime(ts['TIME_PERIOD'])


ts_c = ts.rename(columns = {'TIME_PERIOD':'date', 'OBS_VALUE':'rate'})#to change 'TIME_PERIOD' to 'date', 'OBS_VALUE' to 'rate'
print(ts_c)
```

Comment: i hope this will help if you want somthing more that i can help please coment

Comment: Thanks, but I meant that I don’t want to have headers.  Is there any way to get rid of them?